# Using IF Then Else with Days Between - Cognos

Tags: if-statement, cognos

I'm trying use an if then else statement to calculate the number of days a case has been unassigned.

If the case is classified as unassigned I want to count the days between today, and the day the case was originally created. If the case is not unassigned I want to return just the word assigned. The only two outcomes for Case State Description are Assigned/Unassigned.

The sample I tried based on watching some videos is below, but I am getting several parsing errors, which for some reason I cannot copy from cognos and past here.

```
If ([Case State Description] = 'Unassigned') then (days_between (CURRENT_DATE,[Case Create Date])) else ('Assigned')
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Just a quick follow up, these two lines look identical yet what you provided is working. Being new to this, do you mind telling me what I was missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the following return a result?
If ([Case State Description] = 'Unassigned') then (days_between (CURRENT_DATE,[Case Create Date])) else (1)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see the actual errors.  Looking at your expression it might be a data type issue.  Your if then can result in a numeric or string depending on the record.

Try:
If ([Case State Description] = 'Unassigned') then (cast(days_between (CURRENT_DATE,[Case Create Date]),varchar(4))) else ('Assigned')

If it still fails,  please post the error.